# What was this RPG from the 1980s that incorporated plot points and a flowchart?

Tags: product-identification, story, indie-rpg

I remember seeing some years ago a game aid chart from a game or supplement that made me think it was published in the 1980s or early 90s. It used something it called drama / story / plot points and it had a nifty flow chart where a players success or failure would loop it back to create tension or progress it forward. Unfortunately I can’t recall what the mechanics were and if those ‘points’ were an actual currency or more of an event in a story. There may have been ‘plot’ cards involved as well.

I’ve tried googling it to no avail, but I know if I saw it I would immediately recognize it. My curiosity stems from seeing if this game or supplement used this as a generic story framework for tabletop gaming or if the points, flowchart, and manipulation thereof were part of the game system itself.

Much thanks on any response!

Comment: I believe there are some GM books that contain such charts, but mostly for planning avenues the adventure can flow: do the players want to hunt the dragon for the prince or the population? Then run scene A or B. Do they want to go in via the hidden passage or the main gate?

Comment: Was the game aid chart in color? (If you know either way, it eliminates, like, half of RPG products.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Theatrix

The game you're thinking of is **[Theatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theatrix_(role-playing_game))** (1993). It utilized plot points as its resolution system, and came packaged with [a set of cardstock handout sheets](https://www.darkshire.net/jhkim/rpg/reviews/theatrix.html) that contained the [flow chart](https://dreamingdragonslayer.files.wordpress.com/2021/02/theatrix.jpg?w=1588) you describe.